# Automatic confirmation of replacing folder and files

Tags: powershell, scripting, automation, powershell-2.0, 7zip

I'm running the following command:

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\Abc\xyz.7z" -force | % {& "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" "x" $_.fullname "-oD:\Abc"}
```

After executing above command, a confirmation message is displayed like this.

```
? (Y)es / (N)o / (A)lways / (S)kip all / A(u)to rename all / (Q)uit? q
```

And since I'm doing this in an automated script, so I wanted to accept above options automatically from the script itself. Any luck how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `-y` switch:

```
-y: assume Yes on all queries
```

**Code:**

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\Abc\xyz.7z" -force | % {& "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" "x" $_.fullname "-oD:\Abc" "-y"}
```